# Spring Initializr .gitignore intent (or making sense of the intent)

Tags: git, spring-boot, gitignore, spring-initializr

I'm creating a new Spring Boot app. I'm more than moderately familiar with `.gitignore` patterns, but I see something deliberately templated that has the smell of "intent" on it. The below is produced by the Spring Initializr in many IDEs.

```
target/
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
!**/src/main/**/target/
!**/src/test/**/target/
 ...
 ...
build/
!**/src/main/**/build/
!**/src/test/**/build/
```

I believe this has something to do with maven's multi-module project feature, but Initializr apps are not multi-module (at start). That aside, **what I'm reading here?** If I took a stab at what I think is being stated it is something I do not want to do (as a general practice).

> "Ignore `target/` folders wherever encountered, but `target` folders
> below the top-level in
> `some/path`**`/src/main/`**`deeper/still`**`/target/`** include
> those.
>
> "Oh, do the same for NetBeans `build/` directories!"

This doesn't quite make sense. Why would I ever commit target content generated by the build? Thus I'm trying to deduce the intent of the Spring engineers.

**Update**

In fact, that's exactly what this does, includes `target` or `build` directories deeper in the root. **To what end?**

```sh
mkdir -p some/path/src/main/deeper/still/target/
touch !$/test.txt
```

This new `target` directory is included for staging and commits. Remove this and it's ignored.

Comment: My use of `deeper/still` masked the intent as I also fixated on the use of `target` in the negated exclude statement. I probably would have discovered the intent had a used a more appropriate path, i.e., a package name pattern like `src/main/com/target/api`. I note this in my research below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, these "includes" (negated excludes) make sure directories beneath `src/main` and `src/test` that may be named `target`, for example, a package name, are not missed in a commit.

Per a discussion on the Spring Initializr gitter, Andy Wilkinson, a Spring committer, noted:

> It's to prevent the ignore for Maven's build output directory (`target`) from causing code in a package named `target` from being ignored.

In many cases, safely deleted in individual use cases, "unless you work for Target" (Target Brands, Inc. might have packages namespaced as `com.target.api.*`) (h/t to Andy for the example).

My question should have been answered in the use of `src/main` and `src/test`, but I let the misdirection of the word, `target`, confuse me. In fact, I was demonstrating this in my own example, but couldn't get past the word. D'oh!